# how to use xla with c++ api in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-xla

Tensorflow give a way to run tensorflow graph via XLA，however, it mention nothing about how to run tensorflow graph via XLA using c++ api. 
Counld someone give me some advise?

Answer (score 0):

The guide [Using AOT compilation](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/tfcompile) might not be very clear in each steps.
You can try

1. bazel build tensorflow/compiler/aot/tests:tfcompile_test
2. bazel-bin/tensorflow/compiler/aot/tests/tfcompile_test

as an example.

Answer (score -1):

The other answers so far are of AOT compilation, while I believe JIT is needed in most of times. XLA JIT can be turned on with environment variable. Try using `TF_XLA_FLAGS="--tf_xla_auto_jit=1"`.